# Expanding matrix dimension by multiplication in pytorch

Tags: optimization, pytorch, matrix-multiplication

I am using pytorch and I have tensor A of dimensions [a,b,c] and tensor B with dimensions [a,d]. I want to create tensor C of dimension [a,b,c,d], that is multiplication of elements in A with elements in B with following operation:

```py
for i in range(a):
    for j in range(b):
        for k in range(c):
            for l in range(d):
                C[i,j,k,l]=A[i,j,k]*B[i,l]
```

This works as intended, but is very slow. What would be best practice for such operation in pytorch?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
A.reshape(a, b, c, 1) * B.reshape(a, 1, 1, d)
```

will do the trick.